# How to implement filter text from list box on char change in text box

Tags: windows-phone-7

How to implement Bing search like in wp7,i have list of data in list box by typing a char in text box i should able to filter the data from list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check autocomplete control from Silverlight Toolkit for Windows Phone (it's on codeplex)

Answer (score 0):

In addtion to using `AutoCompleteBox` as argh mentioned, you should use `CollectionViewSource`
http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/news/wp7-Collectionviewsource-filtering

Answer (score 0):

```js
//JQuery: 
 //mobile - netbanking search
 $(document).on('keyup', '#filter', function (e) {
 // Retrieve the input field text and reset the count to zero
 var filter = $(this).val();

 //Regex created to find value in list.
 var pattern = new RegExp(filter, "i");


 // Loop through the comment list
 $(".list").each(function () {
  // If the list item does not contain the text phrase fade it out

  //Trim space from variable value.
  var str = $(this).text().trim();

  if (str.search(pattern) < 0) {
   $(this).fadeOut();
   //Show the list item if the phrase matches and increase the count by 1
  } else {
   $(this).show();
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
JQuery Solution: 
HTML will be: 

<div class="yourlist">

 <input name="" id="filter" type="text" placeholder="Search list" onkeyup="this.setAttribute('value', this.value);" value="">

  <div class="list" style="display: block;">
   Abc
  </div>
  <div class="list" style="display: block;">
   xyz
  </div>
  <div class="list" style="display: block;">
   qwe
  </div>
</div>
```